# Buttons are hiding but not showing when focus is moving in Android

Tags: android

I have some odd requirement. I have some menu buttons.when i am clicking on the buttons some other 3 buttons should visible. But when the focus is moving to another menu button, this 3 buttons should hide or become invisible. i did the first requirement. But unable to do the second. I take the three buttons in a relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativelayout_inventory"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout_menu"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/relativelayout_checkout"
         android:layout_marginTop="10px"
         android:layout_marginLeft="18px"
         android:visibility="invisible"
   >
   <Button android:id="@+id/stckupdt"
        android:background="@drawable/stckupdt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  </Button>

  <Button android:id="@+id/pushoffer"
        android:background="@drawable/stckstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/stckupdt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
  >
  </Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And in the java file, i write the code like below..

```
final Button button_inventory = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inventory);
        final RelativeLayout view_inventory = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_inventory);
        button_inventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view_inventory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are intend to do like Windows menu? I don't know why you need to do that on a phone, but you better look at Touch Event to OnClickListener: [Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

Comment: when the button is not in focus, the other 3 buttons r hidden. when i am clicking the button, 3 buttons r showing. But when i am moving from the button, 3 buttons are not hiding. In the xml, initially i set the relative layout as invisible.

Comment: This is not relative to XML Design, it's just how you arrage the menus. You have to set the visibility of the menus in the onTouch event, they have the value indicate the action (down, up or move). You must set the visibility manually.